# React Native: Disable animations when onPress function is called inside Animated.View

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-navigation

I have a animated view stack which contains a Pressable component to navigate to another screen. But when I press the button, navigation happens after the animation of the container. I want to make it instant.

```
<Animated.View>
  <Animated.View style={[styles.headerContainer, titleStyle]}>
    <Animated.Text style={styles.verificationTitle}>
      {activationBoxTitle}
    </Animated.Text>
    <ArrowRightWhite />
  </Animated.View>
  <Animated.View style={[styles.container, descriptionContainerStyle]}>
    <ImageBackground
      style={styles.backgroundImage}
      resizeMode="cover"
      source={images.activateAccBackground}
    >
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(
          "GeneralQuestions", {
            screen: navigateActivationToPage
          })}
      >
        <Animated.Text style={descriptionStyle}>
          {activationBoxDescription}
        </Animated.Text>
      </Pressable>
    </ImageBackground>
  </Animated.View>
</Animated.View>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a problem like this in a question here and I've also seen it in a project. The most common is before navigation, add a setTimeOut, this will cause a delay and have the animation and navigation. It would look something like this:

```
function handleNavigate() {
 setTimeout(() => {
  navigation.navigate('GeneralQuestions', {
   screen: navigateActivationToPage,
  });
 }, 5000);
}

// ...

<Pressable
  onPress={() => handleNavigate}
/>
```

Then at setTimeOut time, you add a value that makes sense according to your animation